# Minimising an Integrated Relative Entropy Functional

Tags: pr.probability, calculus-of-variations, entropy

Suppose I am given

- A probability distribution on $\mathbf R^d$, with density $\pi (x)$.
- A family of transition kernels $\{ q^0 (x \to \cdot) \}_{x \in \mathbf R^d}$ on $\mathbf R^d$, with densities $q^0 (x \to y)$.

I now want to find a *new* family of transition kernels $\{ q^1 (x \to \cdot) \}_{x \in \mathbf R^d}$ such that

- $q^1$ is in detailed balance with respect to $\pi$, i.e.

\begin{align}
\pi (x) q^1 ( x \to y ) = \pi (y) q^1 ( y \to x)
\end{align}

- $q^1$ are as close as possible to $q^0$ in KL divergence, averaged across $x \sim \pi$.

To this end, I introduce the following functional

\begin{align}
\mathbb{F} [ q^1 ] &= \int_{x \in \mathbf R^d} \pi (x) \cdot KL \left( q^1 (x \to \cdot ) || q^0 (x \to \cdot ) \right) dx\\
&= \int_{x \in \mathbf R^d} \int_{y \in \mathbf R^d} \pi (x) \cdot q^1 (x \to y) \log \frac{ q^1 (x \to y) }{ q^0 (x \to y) } \, dx dy \\
&= \int_{x \in \mathbf R^d} \int_{y \in \mathbf R^d} \pi (x) \cdot \left\{ q^1 (x \to y) \log \frac{ q^1 (x \to y) }{ q^0 (x \to y) } -  q^1 (x \to y) +  q^0 (x \to y) \right \} \, dx dy.
\end{align}

I thus wish to minimise $\mathbb{F}$ over all transition kernels $\{ q^1 (x \to \cdot) \}_{x \in \mathbf R^d}$ satisfying the desired detailed balance condition. Implicitly, there are also the constraints that the $q^1$ are nonnegative and normalised.

I would like to solve this minimisation problem, or at least derive e.g. an Euler-Lagrange equation for it.

Currently, I can show that the first variation of $\mathbb{F}$ is given by

\begin{align}
\left( \frac{d}{dt} \vert_{t = 0} \right) \mathbb{F} [q^1 + t h] =  \int_{x \in \mathbf R^d} \int_{y \in \mathbf R^d} \pi (x) \cdot \log \frac{ q^1 (x \to y) }{ q^0 (x \to y) } \cdot h (x, y) \, dx dy.
\end{align}

Moreover, my constraints stipulate that any admissible variation $h$ must satisfy the following two conditions:

1. $\forall x, y, \quad \pi (x) h (x, y) = \pi (y) h (y, x)$
2. $\forall x, \quad \int_{y \in \mathbf R^d} h (x, y) dy = 0$

I have not been able to translate these conditions into an Euler-Lagrange equation. I acknowledge that since the functional involves no derivatives of $q^1$, the calculus of variations approach may be ill-suited. If readers are able to recommend alternative approaches, this would also be appreciated. Anything which would allow for a more concrete characterisation of the optimal $q^1$ would be ideal.

Comment: I think the reason there's not been much activity on this one is your notation. Am I right to think that your question is of the form "How do I minimise

$$
F(q) = \int \left( q_0 + q \left[ \hspace{.2pc}\mathrm{log}\dfrac{q}{q_0}- 1\right] \right) \hspace{.2pc}\mathrm{d}\mu
$$

with $d\mu(x,y) = \pi(x)\hspace{.2pc}\mathrm{d}x \hspace{.2pc}\mathrm{d}y$ over $q\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^{2d})$ satisfying $\langle$constraints$\rangle$"?

Comment: If so, it might help to add the final form of your problem at the top of the question, and put the rest underneath under a "Context" header. I don't know whether that'll work, but it surely couldn't hurt to get more people interested.

Comment: @DCM thanks for the tips - will update accordingly quite soon. yes, that's pretty much the question.